# Javascript: creating functions pool line with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, line, pool

So I have such [code that simulates function line](http://jsfiddle.net/UcsuB/1/) (`fn1`, `delay`, `fn2`, `delay`, ... `fnN`  - calls a function, removes it from line sleeps a bit and so on).

I have faced strange problem - I see no delay. Why, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `openWindowDelayedPool.add(appendStuff())` will call `appendStuff` immediately and pass the return value to `openWindowDelayedPool.add`. You want to pass the function instead, not call it. There must be other problems with your code though, because I also get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined* (this is in your `setTimeout` callback. The parameter is shadowing the other `val`). But even if these things are fixed, it won't work. The overall logic of this functionality does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are calling `append` immediately, rather than passing a function which will call append.

```
openWindowDelayedPool.add($('.container').append('<p>Test</p>'));
```

should be

```
openWindowDelayedPool.add(function(){
    $('.container').append('<p>Test</p>')
});
```

Even once you fix that, it's not going to work properly however, the first will run but then all subsequent calls will simply find that `isRunning` is true and not execute.

In addition, as mentioned by @FelixKing in the comments:

```
setTimeout( function(val){
```

is incorrect.  You don't want to pass a parameter to this function, just use val within it.

```
setTimeout( function(){
```

Comment: I tried to [fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/UcsuB/2/) but I get only one "Test" instead of 6... Is it because remove removes all identical val's?